# How to Change Plot to Percentage Deviation from Initial Value (the steady state) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

Given the code below, is there an easy way to input some lines that would change the plot from being in levels to percentage deviation from the initial value?

```
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[0 0 15 10])
subplot(2,3,1)
set(gca,'FontSize',16)
plot(time,pe_t,time,pe*ones(N,1),'--','LineWidth',2)
xlim([0 100])
xlabel('Year')
title('Oil price')
```

if it helps, I've included the steady state code below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% STEADY STATE %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


for ir=1:Ir;

r_r(ir)=r;
rmin_r(ir)=rmin;
rmax_r(ir)=rmax;

% KD(ir) = (alpha*Aprod/(r + d))^(1/(1-alpha))*z_ave; % sample code
% w = (1-alpha)*Aprod*KD(ir).^alpha*z_ave^(-alpha);

syms Estar
eqn =  (pe/(alpha*Aprod*( (beta*Aprod*Estar^alpha/(r*p))^(1/(1-beta))*(z_ave)^(gamma/(1-beta)))^beta*z_ave^gamma))^(1/(alpha-1)) - Estar == 0; % eliminate zero
Estar = max(double(solve(eqn,Estar)))

KD(ir) = (beta*Aprod*Estar^alpha/(r*p))^(1/(1-beta))*(z_ave)^(gamma/(1-beta)); %real 
w = Aprod*gamma*Estar^alpha*KD(ir).^beta*z_ave^(gamma-1)/p; %real 

if ir>1
v0 = V_r(:,:,ir-1);
end

v = v0;

for n=1:maxit
    V = v;
    V_n(:,:,n)=V;
    % forward difference
    dVf(1:I-1,:) = (V(2:I,:)-V(1:I-1,:))/da;
    dVf(I,:) = (w*z + r.*amax).^(-ga); %will never be used, but impose state constraint a<=amax just in case
    % backward difference
    dVb(2:I,:) = (V(2:I,:)-V(1:I-1,:))/da;
    dVb(1,:) = (w*z + r.*amin).^(-ga); %state constraint boundary condition
    
    %consumption and savings with forward difference
    cf = dVf.^(-1/ga);
    ssf = w*zz + r.*aa - cf;
    %consumption and savings with backward difference
    cb = dVb.^(-1/ga);
    ssb = w*zz + r.*aa - cb;
    %consumption and derivative of value function at steady state
    c0 = w*zz + r.*aa;
    dV0 = c0.^(-ga);
    
    % dV_upwind makes a choice of forward or backward differences based on
    % the sign of the drift    
    If = ssf > 0; %positive drift --> forward difference
    Ib = ssb < 0; %negative drift --> backward difference
    I0 = (1-If-Ib); %at steady state
    %make sure backward difference is used at amax
    %Ib(I,:) = 1; If(I,:) = 0;
    %STATE CONSTRAINT at amin: USE BOUNDARY CONDITION UNLESS muf > 0:
    %already taken care of automatically
    
    dV_Upwind = dVf.*If + dVb.*Ib + dV0.*I0; %important to include third term
    c = dV_Upwind.^(-1/ga);
    u = c.^(1-ga)/(1-ga);
    
    %CONSTRUCT MATRIX
    X = -min(ssb,0)/da;
    Y = -max(ssf,0)/da + min(ssb,0)/da;
    Z = max(ssf,0)/da;
    
    A1=spdiags(Y(:,1),0,I,I)+spdiags(X(2:I,1),-1,I,I)+spdiags([0;Z(1:I-1,1)],1,I,I);
    A2=spdiags(Y(:,2),0,I,I)+spdiags(X(2:I,2),-1,I,I)+spdiags([0;Z(1:I-1,2)],1,I,I);
    A = [A1,sparse(I,I);sparse(I,I),A2] + Aswitch;

    if max(abs(sum(A,2)))>10^(-9)
       disp('Improper Transition Matrix')
       break
    end
    
    B = (1/Delta + rho)*speye(2*I) - A;

    u_stacked = [u(:,1);u(:,2)];
    V_stacked = [V(:,1);V(:,2)];
    
    b = u_stacked + V_stacked/Delta;
    V_stacked = B\b; %SOLVE SYSTEM OF EQUATIONS
    
    V = [V_stacked(1:I),V_stacked(I+1:2*I)];
    
    Vchange = V - v;
    v = V;

    dist(n) = max(max(abs(Vchange)));
    if dist(n)<crit
        disp('Value Function Converged, Iteration = ')
        disp(n)
        break
    end
end
toc;
```

Please respond if I'm omitting important details.

I tried reading plotting documentation for matlab, specifically for `plot(time,pe_t,time` this section of the plotting function, but I couldn't come up with anything. However my intuition is that changing something in this line will return what I desire.